# 2003 Giant Rainier MTB Leaking Shock Fluid?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, shocks

I have a 2003 Giant Rainier as shown here: https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=38863

that appears to be leaking a little bit of fluid from one of its front shocks.  I think it has only leaked a few milliliters.

What would be the best & cheapest way to fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec fork on that was the Answer Manitou Axel Super -  [information here](https://manitoumtb.com/documentation/)

From the 2003 Axel user manual....

> CHECKING OIL LEVEL IMPORTANT: Setting the proper oil level in your
>   Fluid Flow damped fork is critical. Fluid Flow damping is located in
>   the right leg of your Manitou AXEL fork. Not enough oil will allow
>   foaming and reduce the performance. Too much oil will restrict travel
>   and may cause damage to the system and create an unsafe riding
>   condition. Finish reading this entire section prior to altering the
>   oil level. To check the oil level on the Manitou AXEL, remove the
>   compression assembly located in the top of the right leg (as you are
>   looking at the fork from the rider’s position). Leave the left side
>   spring stack in place to keep the fork fully extended. Use a tape
>   measure or “dip stick” to measure from the top of the fork crown down
>   to where the oil sits (Figure 2). The oil level for the Manitou AXEL
>   should be per following table. Fork Model Oil Level Manitou AXEL 
>   115-125 mm (4.5-4.9”) NOTE: Use SAE 5WT fork oil suspension fluid
>   only.
>
> Forks need regular servicing - anything as often as every 25 hours
>   with seal replacement commonly being recommended at 100hours riding (I
>   think Manitou had relatibvely long service intervals . Seal
>   replacement and lower leg service is not too hard, but is a bigger job
>   than many owners are prepared to tackle themselves.  A shop secive
>   with seal replacement will be around $US100 (various with you location
>   in the world).

The seals have gone - possible just from old age and wear. Given the age and value of the bike, its likely not worth the cost of new seals, especially if you are getting a shop to do it.  If you don;t want to pull the fork apart, replacing the oil is straight forward, but I would be tempted to do a lower leg service and then top up the oil regularly.

The oil leaking is a messy problem, but no causing functional issues as long as there is oil to leak out. If the leak stops its time to worry.

Comment: Googling suggests the fork is mid-range so given its lasted 15 years, a service kit would be more affordable than a replacement fork.